# how to restrict dragging of a d3 tree layout to certain portion of the page.here si the code i am using

Tags: d3.js

here is the code ,i am using it.it is allowing dragging to any where in the page.need to restrict it to certain portion of the page.here is the code ,i am using it.it is allowing dragging to any where in the page.need to restrict it to certain portion of the page.here is the code ,i am using it.it is allowing dragging to any where in the page.
                              var tooltipMap = d3.map();
                var vmMap = d3.map();
                var vmLength = 0;
                var vmOne = '';

```
            var totalNodes = 0, maxLabelLength = 15;
            // variables for drag/drop
            var selectedNode = null, draggingNode = null;
            // panning variables
            var panSpeed = 200, panBoundary = 20; // Within 20px from edges will pan when
            // dragging.
            // Misc. variables
            var i = 0, duration = 750;
            var root;

            // size of the diagram
            var docWidth, viewerWidth, docHeight, halfHeight, quarterHeight, viewerHeight;

            var tree, zoomListener, svgGroup, baseSvg;

            /**
             * define a d3 diagonal projection for use by the node paths later on.
             */
            var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal().projection(function(d) {
                return [ d.x, -d.y ];
            });

            // Get JSON data
            treeJSON = d3.json("network.json", function(error, treeData) {

                // size of the diagram
                docWidth = $(document).width();
                viewerWidth = docWidth / (1.361);
                docHeight = $(document).height();
                halfHeight = docHeight / 2;
                quarterHeight = docHeight / 4;
                viewerHeight = halfHeight + quarterHeight;

                tree = d3.layout.tree().size([ viewerHeight, viewerWidth ]);

                // Call visit function to establish maxLabelLength
                visit(treeData, function(d) {
                    totalNodes++;
                    maxLabelLength = Math.max(d.name.length, maxLabelLength);

                }, function(d) {
                    return d.children && d.children.length > 0 ? d.children : null;
                });

                // Sort the tree initially incase the JSON isn't in a sorted
                // order.
                sortTree();
                function pan(domNode, direction) {
                    var speed = panSpeed;
                    if (panTimer) {
                        clearTimeout(panTimer);
                        translateCoords = d3.transform(svgGroup.attr("transform"));
                        if (direction == 'left' || direction == 'right') {
                            translateX = direction == 'left' ? translateCoords.translate[0] + speed : translateCoords.translate[0]
                                    - speed;
                            translateY = translateCoords.translate[1];
                        } else if (direction == 'up' || direction == 'down') {
                            translateX = translateCoords.translate[0];
                            translateY = direction == 'up' ? translateCoords.translate[1] + speed : translateCoords.translate[1]
                                    - speed;
                        }
                        scaleX = translateCoords.scale[0];
                        scaleY = translateCoords.scale[1];
                        scale = zoomListener.scale();
                        svgGroup.transition().attr("transform",
                                "translate(" + translateX + "," + translateY + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
                        d3.select(domNode).select('g.node').attr("transform", "translate(" + translateX + "," + translateY + ")");
                        zoomListener.scale(zoomListener.scale());
                        zoomListener.translate([ translateX, translateY ]);
                        panTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                            pan(domNode, speed, direction);
                        }, 50);
                    }
                }

                // Define the zoom function for the zoomable tree

                function zoom() {
                    svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
                }

                // define the zoomListener which calls the zoom function on the
                // "zoom" event constrained within the scaleExtents
                zoomListener = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([ 0.1, 3 ]).on("zoom", zoom);

                function initiateDrag(d, domNode) {
                    draggingNode = d;
                    d3.select(domNode).select('.ghostCircle').attr('pointer-events', 'none');
                    d3.selectAll('.ghostCircle').attr('class', 'ghostCircle show');
                    d3.select(domNode).attr('class', 'node activeDrag');

                    svgGroup.selectAll("g.node").sort(function(a, b) { 
                        if (a.id != draggingNode.id)
                            return 1; // a is not the hovered element,
                        // send "a" to the back
                        else
                            return -1; // a is the hovered element,
                        // bring "a" to the front
                    });
                    // if nodes has children, remove the links and nodes
                    if (nodes.length > 1) {
                        // remove link paths
                        links = tree.links(nodes);
                        nodePaths = svgGroup.selectAll("path.link").data(links, function(d) {
                            return d.target.id;
                        }).remove();
                        // remove child nodes
                        nodesExit = svgGroup.selectAll("g.node").data(nodes, function(d) {
                            return d.id;
                        }).filter(function(d, i) {
                            if (d.id == draggingNode.id) {
                                return false;
                            }
                            return true;
                        }).remove();
                    }

                    // remove parent link
                    parentLink = tree.links(tree.nodes(draggingNode.parent));
                    svgGroup.selectAll('path.link').filter(function(d, i) {
                        if (d.target.id == draggingNode.id) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }).remove();

                    dragStarted = null;
                }

                // define the baseSvg, attaching a class for styling and the
                // zoomListener
                baseSvg = d3.select("#tree-container").append("svg").attr("width", viewerWidth).attr("height", viewerHeight).attr(
                        "class", "overlay").call(zoomListener);

                // Define the drag listeners for drag/drop behaviour of nodes.
                dragListener = d3.behavior.drag().on("dragstart", function(d) {
                    if (d == root) {
                        return;
                    }
                    dragStarted = true;
                    nodes = tree.nodes(d);
                    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
                    // it's important that we suppress the mouseover
                    // event on the node being dragged. Otherwise it
                    // will absorb the mouseover event and the
                    // underlying node will not detect it
                    // d3.select(this).attr('pointer-events',
                    // 'none');
                }).on("drag", function(d) {
                    if (d == root) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (dragStarted) {
                        domNode = this;
                        initiateDrag(d, domNode);
                    }

                    // get coords of mouseEvent relative to svg
                    // container to allow for panning
                    relCoords = d3.mouse($('svg').get(0));
                    if (relCoords[0] < panBoundary) {
                        panTimer = true;
                        pan(this, 'left');
                    } else if (relCoords[0] > ($('svg').width() - panBoundary)) {

                        panTimer = true;
                        pan(this, 'right');
                    } else if (relCoords[1] < panBoundary) {
                        panTimer = true;
                        pan(this, 'up');
                    } else if (relCoords[1] > ($('svg').height() - panBoundary)) {
                        panTimer = true;
                        pan(this, 'down');
                    } else {
                        try {
                            clearTimeout(panTimer);
                        } catch (e) {

                        }
                    }

                    d.x0 += d3.event.dy;
                    d.y0 += d3.event.dx;
                    var node = d3.select(this);
                    node.attr("transform", "translate(" + d.y0 + "," + d.x0 + ")");
                    updateTempConnector();
                }).on("dragend", function(d) {
                    if (d == root) {
                        return;
                    }
                    domNode = this;
                    if (selectedNode) {
                        // now remove the element from the
                        // parent, and insert it into the new
                        // elements children
                        var index = draggingNode.parent.children.indexOf(draggingNode);
                        if (index > -1) {
                            draggingNode.parent.children.splice(index, 1);
                        }
                        if (typeof selectedNode.children !== 'undefined' || typeof selectedNode._children !== 'undefined') {
                            if (typeof selectedNode.children !== 'undefined') {
                                selectedNode.children.push(draggingNode);
                            } else {
                                selectedNode._children.push(draggingNode);
                            }
                        } else {
                            selectedNode.children = [];
                            selectedNode.children.push(draggingNode);
                        }
                        // Make sure that the node being added
                        // to is expanded so user can see added
                        // node is correctly moved
                        expand(selectedNode);
                        sortTree();
                        endDrag();
                    } else {
                        endDrag();
                    }
                });

                function endDrag() {
                    selectedNode = null;
                    d3.selectAll('.ghostCircle').attr('class', 'ghostCircle');
                    d3.select(domNode).attr('class', 'node');
                    // now restore the mouseover event or we won't be able to
                    // drag a 2nd time
                    d3.select(domNode).select('.ghostCircle').attr('pointer-events', '');
                    updateTempConnector();
                    if (draggingNode !== null) {
                        update(root);
                        centerNode(draggingNode);
                        draggingNode = null;
                    }
                }

                // Helper functions for collapsing and expanding nodes.

                function collapse(d) {
                    if (d.children) {
                        d._children = d.children;
                        d._children.forEach(collapse);
                        d.children = null;
                    }
                }

                function expand(d) {
                    if (d._children) {
                        d.children = d._children;
                        d.children.forEach(expand);
                        d._children = null;
                    }
                }

                var overCircle = function(d) {
                    selectedNode = d;
                    updateTempConnector();
                };
                var outCircle = function(d) {
                    selectedNode = null;
                    updateTempConnector();
                };

                // Function to update the temporary connector indicating
                // dragging affiliation
                var updateTempConnector = function() {
                    var data = [];
                    if (draggingNode !== null && selectedNode !== null) {
                        // have to flip the source coordinates since we did this
                        // for the existing connectors on the original tree
                        data = [ {
                            source : {
                                x : selectedNode.y0,
                                y : selectedNode.x0
                            },
                            target : {
                                x : draggingNode.y0,
                                y : draggingNode.x0
                            }
                        } ];
                    }
                    var link = svgGroup.selectAll(".templink").data(data);

                    link.enter().append("path").attr("class", "templink").attr("d", d3.svg.diagonal()).attr('pointer-events',
                            'none');

                    link.attr("d", d3.svg.diagonal());

                    d3.selectAll("#stoIdlink").attr("class", "invisible");
                    d3.selectAll("#childIdlink").attr("class", "invisible");

                    link.exit().remove();
                };

                // Append a group which holds all nodes and which the zoom
                // Listener can act upon.
                svgGroup = baseSvg.append("g");

                // Define the root
                root = treeData;
                root.x0 = viewerHeight / 2;
                root.y0 = 0;

                /**
                 * The below method is called to add buttons in UI
                 */
                addLoadSLAButtons();

                /** End of method to add buttons.* */

                // Layout the tree initially and center on the root node.
                update(root);
                centerNode(root);
                collapseFirstVM();

            });

            /**
             * This function is used to set all nodes for network frame
             * 
             * @param source
             * @return
             */
            function update(source) {

                // Compute the new height, function counts total children of
                // root node and sets tree height accordingly.
                // This prevents the layout looking squashed when new nodes
                // are made visible or looking sparse when nodes are removed
                // This makes the layout more consistent.
                var levelWidth = [ 1 ];
                var childCount = function(level, n) {

                    if (n.children && n.children.length > 0) {
                        if (levelWidth.length <= level + 1)
                            levelWidth.push(10);

                        levelWidth[level + 1] += n.children.length;
                        n.children.forEach(function(d) {
                            childCount(level + 1, d);
                        });
                    }
                };
                childCount(0, root);
                var newHeight = d3.max(levelWidth) * 25;
                tree = tree.size([ newHeight, viewerWidth ]);

                // Compute the new tree layout.
                var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(), links = tree.links(nodes);

                // Set widths between levels based on maxLabelLength.
                nodes.forEach(function(d, i) {
                    d.y = (d.depth * (maxLabelLength * 7));
                    /** The below code is used to add nodes in map* */
                    if (nodes[i] != null && nodes[i] != 'undefined') {
                        if (nodes[i].type == "appServer") {
                            var toolMap = d3.map();
                            toolMap.set("connId", d.connServer);
                            toolMap.set("id", d.id);
                            toolMap.set("type", "Web server");
                            toolMap.set("x", d.x);
                            toolMap.set("y", d.y);
                            tooltipMap.set(d.id, toolMap);
                        } else if (nodes[i].type == "webServer") {
                            var toolMap = d3.map();
                            toolMap.set("connId", d.connServer);
                            toolMap.set("id", d.id);
                            toolMap.set("type", "Web server");
                            toolMap.set("x", d.x);
                            toolMap.set("y", d.y);
                            tooltipMap.set(d.id, toolMap);
                        } else if (nodes[i].type == "dataServer") {
                            var toolMap = d3.map();
                            toolMap.set("connId", d.connServer);
                            toolMap.set("id", d.id);
                            toolMap.set("type", "Web server");
                            toolMap.set("x", d.x);
                            toolMap.set("y", d.y);
                            tooltipMap.set(d.id, toolMap);
                        } else if (nodes[i].type == "container") {
                            var toolMap = d3.map();
                            toolMap.set("id", d.id);
                            toolMap.set("x", d.x);
                            toolMap.set("y", d.y);
                            tooltipMap.set(d.id, toolMap);
                        } else if (nodes[i].type == "sto") {
                            var toolMap = d3.map();
                            toolMap.set("id", d.id);
                            toolMap.set("x", d.x);
                            toolMap.set("y", d.y);
                            tooltipMap.set(d.id, toolMap);
                        } else if (nodes[i].type == "lb") {
                            var toolMap = d3.map();
                            toolMap.set("id", d.id);
                            toolMap.set("x", d.x);
                            toolMap.set("y", d.y);
                            tooltipMap.set(d.id, toolMap);
                        } else if (nodes[i].type == "vm") {
                            var toolMap = d3.map();
                            toolMap.set("id", d.id);
                            toolMap.set("x", d.x);
                            toolMap.set("y", d.y);
                            tooltipMap.set(d.id, toolMap);
                        }
                    }
                    /** My code ends here */

                });

                // Update the nodes…
                node = svgGroup.selectAll("g.node").data(nodes, function(d) {
                    return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
                });

                // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
                var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g").call(dragListener).attr("class", "node").attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
                }).on('click', click);

                /**
                 * The below code adds circle out of the server nodes to show connection
                 * between them.
                 */
                nodeEnter.append("circle").attr({
                    r : 22
                }).attr("id", function(d, i) {
                    if (nodes[i].type == "appServer") {
                        return "outer" + nodes[i].id;
                    } else if (nodes[i].type == "webServer") {
                        return "outer" + nodes[i].id;
                    } else if (nodes[i].type == "dataServer") {
                        return "outer" + nodes[i].id;
                    }
                }).style("fill", "transparent").style("stroke-width", function(d, i) {
                    if (nodes[i].type == "appServer") {
                        return "1";
                    } else if (nodes[i].type == "webServer") {
                        return "1";
                    } else if (nodes[i].type == "dataServer") {
                        return "1";
                    } else {
                        return "0";
                    }
                }).style("stroke", "#fff");

                /** End of code which is used to connect servers* */

                nodeEnter.append("circle").attr("r", 10).attr("id", function(d, i) {
                    return nodes[i].id;
                }).style("filter", function(d, i) {
                    if (nodes[i].type == "vm") {
                        if (d.children == 'undefined' || d.children == null) {
                            return "url(#virtualMacCollapse)";
                        } else {
                            return "url(#virtualMac)";
                        }
                    } else if (nodes[i].type == "container") {
                        if (d.children == 'undefined' || d.children == null) {
                            return "url(#containerCollapse)";
                        } else {
                            return "url(#container)";
                        }

                    } else if (nodes[i].type == "appServer") {
                        return "url(#appserver)";
                    } else if (nodes[i].type == "webServer") {
                        return "url(#webserver)";
                    } else if (nodes[i].type == "dataServer") {
                        return "url(#dbserver)";
                    } else if (nodes[i].type == "network") {
                        if (d.children == 'undefined' || d.children == null) {
                            return "url(#networkCollapse)";
                        } else {
                            return "url(#network)";
                        }
                    } else if (nodes[i].type == "lb") {
                        return "url(#loadbalancer)";
                    } else if (nodes[i].type == "sto") {
                        return "url(#storage)";
                    }

                }).style("fill", function(d) {
                    return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                }).on("mouseover", function(d) {
                    getConServers(this, d3.event, "enter");
                }).on("mouseout", function(d) {
                    getConServers(this, d3.event, "exit");
                });

                nodeEnter.append("text").attr("x", function(d) {
                    return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
                }).attr("dy", ".35em").attr('class', 'nodeText').attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
                    return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
                }).text(function(d) {
                    return d.name;
                }).style("fill-opacity", 0);

                // phantom node to give us mouseover in a radius around it
                nodeEnter.append("circle").attr('class', 'ghostCircle').attr("r", 30).attr("opacity", 0.2) // change

                .style("fill", "red").attr('pointer-events', 'mouseover').on("mouseover", function(node) {
                    overCircle(node);
                }).on("mouseout", function(node) {
                    outCircle(node);
                });

                // Update the text to reflect whether node has children or
                // not.
                node.select('text').attr("x", function(d) {
                    return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
                }).attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
                    return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
                }).text(function(d) {
                    return d.name;
                });

                // Change the circle fill depending on whether it has
                // children and is collapsed
                node.select("circle.nodeCircle").attr("r", 4.5).style("fill", function(d) {
                    return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                });

                // Transition nodes to their new position.
                var nodeUpdate = node.transition().duration(duration).attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + (d.x - 6) + "," + -d.y + ")";
                });

                // Fade the text in
                nodeUpdate.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 1);

                // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
                var nodeExit = node.exit().transition().duration(duration).attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
                }).remove();

                nodeExit.select("circle").attr("r", 0);

                nodeExit.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 0);

                // Update the links…
                var link = svgGroup.selectAll("path.link").data(links, function(d) {
                    return d.target.id;
                });

                // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.

                link.enter().insert("path", "g").attr("class", "link").attr("id", function(d, i) {
                    return d.target.id + "link";
                }).attr("stroke-dasharray", function(d) {
                    return (d.source.parent) ? "6,6" : "1,0";
                }).attr("d", function(d) {
                    var o = {
                        x : source.x0,
                        y : source.y0
                    };
                    return diagonal({
                        source : o,
                        target : o
                    });
                });

                d3.selectAll("#stoIdlink").attr("class", "invisible");
                d3.selectAll("#childIdlink").attr("class", "invisible");

                // Transition links to their new position.
                link.transition().duration(duration).attr("d", diagonal);

                // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
                link.exit().transition().duration(duration).attr("d", function(d) {
                    var o = {
                        x : source.x,
                        y : source.y
                    };
                    return diagonal({
                        source : o,
                        target : o
                    });
                }).remove();

                // Stash the old positions for transition.
                nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                    /** My changes to get the first VM id if total VM count exceeds 4 */
                    if (d.type == "vm") {
                        var toolMap = d3.map();
                        toolMap.set("id", d.id.id);
                        toolMap.set("type", "VM");
                        vmMap.set(d.id, toolMap);
                        vmLength = vmLength + 1;
                        if (vmLength > 3) {
                            vmOne = d.id;
                        }
                    }
                    /** End of my changes */
                    d.x0 = d.x;
                    d.y0 = d.y;

                });

            }

            /**
             * Function to center node when clicked/dropped so node doesn't get lost when
             * collapsing/moving with large amount of children.
             */
            function centerNode(source) {
                scale = zoomListener.scale();
                x = -source.y0;
                y = -source.x0;
                x = x * scale + viewerWidth / 2;
                y = y * scale + viewerHeight / 2;
                /** My Changes-starts here* */
                x = 226.83688;
                y = 361.125;
                /** My changes-ends here* */
                d3.select('g').transition().duration(duration).attr("transform",
                        "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
                zoomListener.scale(scale);
                zoomListener.translate([ x, y ]);
                var shootX = "850.242468772961";
                var shootY = "450.75";
                getShootImage(shootX, shootY);
                // mouseovertip(d);
            }

            /**
             * This function is used to add shooting image and text into the frame.
             * 
             * @param shootImgX
             * @param shootTextX
             * @return
             */
            function getShootImage(shootImgX, shootImgY) {
                d3.select("#shootCircle").remove();
                var imgUrl = "image/target-icon.png";

                baseSvg.append("image").attr("id", "shootCircle").attr("xlink:href", imgUrl).attr("x", shootImgX).attr("y",
                        shootImgY).attr("width", 50).attr("height", 50).style("fill", "red").classed("shoot", true);

                baseSvg.append("text").text("Shooting Gun").attr("x", shootImgX).attr("y", shootImgY + 50).attr("width", 50).attr(
                        "height", 50).style("font-weight", "bold");

            }

            /**
             * Toggle children function
             */
            function toggleChildren(d) {
                if (d.children) {
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d.children = null;
                } else if (d._children) {
                    d.children = d._children;
                    d._children = null;
                }
                return d;
            }
            /*******************************************************************************
             * The below change has been made to collapse the first node , if the total VM
             * count exceeds 3.
             */

            function collapseFirstVM() {
                var levelWidth = [ 1 ];
                var childCount = function(level, n) {

                    if (n.children && n.children.length > 0) {
                        if (levelWidth.length <= level + 1)
                            levelWidth.push(0);

                        levelWidth[level + 1] += n.children.length;
                        n.children.forEach(function(d) {
                            childCount(level + 1, d);
                        });
                    }
                };
                childCount(0, root);
                var newHeight = d3.max(levelWidth) * 25; // 25 pixels per
                // line
                tree = tree.size([ newHeight, viewerWidth ]);

                // Compute the new tree layout.
                var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(), links = tree.links(nodes);
                nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                    if (vmLength > 3) {
                        if (d.id == vmOne) {
                            d = toggleChildren(d);
                            update(d);
                            centerNode(d);
                            d3.select("#" + d.id).style("filter", "url(#virtualMacCollapse)");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            /**
             * This function is used to add buttons in network topology.
             * 
             * @return
             */
            function addLoadSLAButtons() {
                var slaDiv = document.createElement("div");
                slaDiv.setAttribute("id", "slaDiv");
                slaDiv.style.position = "relative";
                slaDiv.style.left = "35px";
                slaDiv.style.top = "-300px";
                slaDiv.style.width = "100px";

                var slaButton = document.createElement("input");
                slaButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
                slaButton.setAttribute("value", "View/Modify ServiceContract");
                slaButton.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-info");
                slaButton.setAttribute("id", "addSla");
                slaButton.style.position = "absolute";
                slaButton.setAttribute("onclick", "");// this will be modified once we
                // receive clarification on the
                // functionality.

                document.getElementById("tree-container").appendChild(slaDiv);
                document.getElementById("slaDiv").appendChild(slaButton);

                var relDiv = document.createElement("div");
                relDiv.setAttribute("id", "relDiv");
                relDiv.style.position = "relative";
                relDiv.style.left = "35px";
                relDiv.style.top = "-250px";
                relDiv.style.width = "100px";

                var loadButton = document.createElement("input");
                loadButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
                loadButton.setAttribute("value", "Add Load");
                loadButton.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-cust-info");
                loadButton.setAttribute("id", "addload");
                loadButton.style.position = "absolute";
                loadButton.style.align = "left";

                loadButton.setAttribute("onclick", "reLoadPage()");

                document.getElementById("tree-container").appendChild(relDiv);
                document.getElementById("relDiv").appendChild(loadButton);

            }

            /**
             * A recursive helper function for performing some setup by walking through all
             * nodes
             */
            function visit(parent, visitFn, childrenFn) {
                if (!parent)
                    return;

                visitFn(parent);

                var children = childrenFn(parent);
                if (children) {
                    var count = children.length;
                    for ( var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        visit(children[i], visitFn, childrenFn);
                    }
                }
            }
            /**
             * This function is used to show the connections between servers
             * 
             * @param element
             * @param event
             * @param status
             * @return
             */
            function getConServers(element, event, status) {
                var conServerNode;
                var targetElement = event.target;
                var targetId = targetElement.id;

                if (targetId != null) {
                    var server = tooltipMap.get(targetElement.id);
                    if (server != null) {
                        var connectedServer = server.get("connId");
                        var outerTarget = d3.select("#" + "outer" + targetId);
                        var outerCon = d3.select("#" + "outer" + connectedServer);
                        if (status == "enter") {

                            outerTarget.style("stroke", "#48C127");
                            outerTarget.style("stroke-width", 3);
                            outerCon.style("stroke", "#F07A0B");
                            outerCon.style("stroke-width", 3);

                        } else if (status == "exit") {
                            outerTarget.style("stroke", "#fff");
                            outerCon.style("stroke", "#fff");
                            outerTarget.style("stroke-width", 1);
                            outerCon.style("stroke-width", 1);

                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            /**
             * sort the tree according to the node names
             */
            function sortTree() {
                tree.sort(function(a, b) {
                    return b.name.toLowerCase() < a.name.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
                });
            }

            /**
             * This function is used to perform collapse or expand operations when node is
             * clicked
             * 
             * @param d
             * @return
             */
            function click(d) {
                addDetailsDiv(d.id, d.name, d.type);
                if (d3.event.defaultPrevented || d.id == 'lbNodeId' || d.id == 'stoNodeId')
                    return; // click suppressed
                d = toggleChildren(d);
                if (d.id != null && d.id != 'undefined' && d.id != 'stoId') {
                    var image = d3.select("#" + d.id).style("filter");
                    if (image.indexOf("virtualMacCollapse") != -1) {
                        d3.select("#" + d.id).style("filter", "url(#virtualMac)");
                    } else if (image.indexOf("virtualMac") != -1) {
                        d3.select("#" + d.id).style("filter", "url(#virtualMacCollapse)");
                    }

                    else if (image.indexOf("containerCollapse") != -1) {
                        d3.select("#" + d.id).style("filter", "url(#container)");
                    } else if (image.indexOf("container") != -1) {
                        d3.select("#" + d.id).style("filter", "url(#containerCollapse)");
                    } else if (image.indexOf("networkCollapse") != -1) {
                        d3.select("#" + d.id).style("filter", "url(#network)");
                    } else if (image.indexOf("network") != -1) {
                        d3.select("#" + d.id).style("filter", "url(#networkCollapse)");
                    }

                }

                update(d);
                centerNode(d);
                if (d.id != null && (d.id == "stoNodeId" || d.id == "lbNodeId")) {
                    d3.selectAll("#childIdlink").attr("class", "invisible");
                    d3.selectAll("#stoIdlink").attr("class", "invisible");
                }

            }

            function addDetailsDiv(nodeId, nodeName, nodeType) {
                var detailsDiv = document.createElement("div");
                detailsDiv.setAttribute("id", "detailsDiv");
                detailsDiv.style.position = "relative";
                detailsDiv.style.left = "35px";
                detailsDiv.style.top = "-200px";
                detailsDiv.style.width = "150px";
                document.getElementById("tree-container").appendChild(detailsDiv);

                var innerHtmlStr = "<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"2\" style=\"text-align: left;font-weight: bold\" color=\"#0B0B0B\">Node Properties</font>"
                        + "<table id=\"propTable\">"
                        + "<tr><td>Node Id&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</td><td align=\"left\">&nbsp;&nbsp;"
                        + nodeId
                        + "</td></tr>"
                        + "<tr><td>Node Name&nbsp;&nbsp;:</td><td align=\"left\">&nbsp;&nbsp;"
                        + nodeName
                        + "</td></tr>"
                        + "<tr><td>Node Type&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</td><td align=\"left\"> &nbsp;&nbsp;"
                        + nodeType + "</td></tr>"
                        + "</table>";
                document.getElementById("detailsDiv").innerHTML = innerHtmlStr;

            }
```

Comment: Are you dragging particular nodes or whole tree..?can you make fiddle..?

Comment: can you make your tried code in fiddle,easy to figure out the problem

Comment: not able to prepare the fiddle as of now,hence posted the code which i ma using in the above query.please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: tree almost similar to : http://www.robschmuecker.com/d3-js-drag-and-drop-zoomable-panning-collapsible-tree-with-auto-sizing/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/fF4L4/2/ ,this is almost similar to mine.Need to restrict the dragging to certain area of the page